# Android Tests - How to add Espresso Logs

Tags: android, continuous-integration, android-espresso

I´m using

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
        // this library uses the newest app compat v22 but the espresso contrib still v21.
        // you have to specifically exclude the older versions of the contrib library or
        // there will be some conflicts
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

for tests and was wondering if there´s a way to say to espresso to print a log with the started test and the finished test so will be easy to see the logcat if something happens.

That will be great to mix with papertrail to check why tests are failing and where with private integration servers.

Comment: It already print logs... `TestRunner  I  started: successCloseView`

Comment: Seriously, is there no way to actually add debugging log / console entries to an Espresso test?  When the existing output is not enough, this is a natural next step: add moar logging.

Answer (score 8):

You can capture Android Logs by running tests on your CI server through [Spoon](http://square.github.io/spoon/).  See how-to examples on their website and check out the links below for example reports and then the logs for one of the tests.  Each test run has the logs captured and saved in the report.

Report Output: http://square.github.io/spoon/sample/index.html

Example Logs: http://square.github.io/spoon/sample/logs/0403681E12013007/com.example.spoon.ordering.tests.OrderActivityTest/testMakeASandwich_ItTastesGood.html

Answer (score 3):

Next time please show us what steps you took to get this working yourself.

You can just look in logcat after running tests. Some of the helper classes already log to logcat. For example look at 
`android.support.test.internal.runner.lifecycle.ActivityLifecycleMonitorImpl`. It logs activity lifecycle states:

```
D/LifecycleMonitor: Lifecycle status change:com.example.android.MyActivity@f3c7955 in: STOPPED
```

Any log statements inside *your* classes under test will also get displayed. Finally any log statements inside your *test classes* will get displayed.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SomeTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Log.d(TAG, "setup");
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm able to see the logs in both Android Studio and the command line.

I'll wrap up by saying that I'm also able to get the logging to work if when using Timber instead.

Comment: Right. Simply using `Log.d` works fine. I could see the logging appear in android studio's 'Android Monitor'.

Answer (score 3):

I've checked the code of the framework and it seems it uses System.out.println which works also in tests. Android log sadly doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a [TestWatcher](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) and setup your own Logger with a TAG to filter on.

Assign the TestWatcher as a Rule to your test. I personally like to use a [Rule Chain](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html) as I'll have several TestWatchers (For example: to capture a screenshot on failures).

```
@get:Rule
val chain: RuleChain = RuleChain
    .outerRule(ScenarioRule())
    .around(ScreenshotRule())
```

Within my Scenario rule, I'll print out with my custom logger when a test starts and finishes:

```
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher
import org.junit.runner.Description

class ScenarioRule: TestWatcher() {

    var testLog = TestLog()

    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        testLog.info("Starting: ${description.displayName}")
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description) {
        testLog.info("Finished: ${description.displayName}")
    }
}
```

A snippet of my custom test logger:

```
import android.util.Log
const val TAG = "AUTOMATION"

class TestLog {

    fun info(message: String) {
        Log.i(TAG, "$message")
    }
    fun warn(message: String) {
        Log.w(TAG, "$message")
    }
```

Then within Logcat create a new Filter based on the your Tag

```
2021-11-19 15:54:22.241 11621-11673/com.example I/AUTOMATION: Starting: loginWithCredentials(com.example.tests.LoginFlowUITest)
2021-11-19 15:54:35.669 11621-11673/com.example I/AUTOMATION: Finished: loginWithCredentials(com.example.tests.LoginFlowUITest)
```

Proceed to add as much details as you like and reuse this Logger for your test steps.